# how to call the function once at a time?

Tags: php

I'm working on my PHP script to call the function once at a time when I click the link on my site.

When I click the link on my site to connect to the get-listing.php script, it will call to both function of tvguidecom and skyuk at the same time which it will output one of those webpage.

I think the problem are on this line:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
   tvguidecom($row);
   skyuk($row);
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
$link;
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

function db_connect()
{
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', 'mydbname');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mydbpassword');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');

  $errmsg_arr = array();
  $errflag = false;
  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

  if(!$link) 
  {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$db) 
  {
    die("Unable to select database");
  }
}

function tvguidecom($row)
{
  include ('tvguide.get-listing.php');
}
function tvguide2($row)
{
  include ('skyuk.php');
}
db_connect();


function clean($var)
{
  return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($var));
}

$channels = "";
$id = "";

if(isset($_GET['channels']))
{
  $channels = $_GET['channels'];
}
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
  $id = $_GET['id'];
}

if($errflag) 
{
  $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
  echo implode('<br />',$errmsg_arr);
}
else 
{
  $insert = array();

  if(isset($_GET['channels'])) 
  {
    $insert[] = 'channels = \'' . clean($_GET['channels']) .'\'';
  }
  if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
  {
    $insert[] = 'id = \'' . clean($_GET['id']) . '\'';
  }

  if($channels && $id) 
  {
    $qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, links FROM tvguide WHERE channels='$channels' && id='$id'";
    $result1=mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
      tvguidecom($row);
      skyuk($row);
    }
    mysql_close();
    exit;
  }
  else if(!$channels && ! $id) 
  {
    $qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, links, streams FROM tvguide";
    $result1=mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
    {
      echo "<p id='channels'>".$row["id"]. " " . $row["channels"]. "</p>";
      echo '<a id="link1" href="http://example.com/get-listing.php?channels=' . $row["channels"] . "&id=" . $row["id"] . '">http://example.com/get-listing.php?channels=' . $row["channels"] . "&id=" . $row["id"] . '</a><br><br>';

      //echo "<p id='links'>";

      //echo '<a id="link1" href="http://example.com/get-listing.php?channels=' . $row["channels"] . "&id=" . $row["id"] . "'>http://example.com/get-listing.php?channels=" . $row["channels"] . "&id=" . $row["id"] .'>test</a></p>';
      //echo '<a id="link1" href="http://example.com/get-listing.php?channels=';

      echo '<a id="streams" href="' . $row['streams'] . '">Stream 1</a><br><br>';
    }
  } 
}
?>
```

I want to call either of function once at a time when I click the link on my site. Example: I want to call tvguidecom function to see if it will output the data in my get-listing script or else move on to the next function and call the skyuk function.

Can you please show me an example of how I can call the function once at a time when I click the link on my site?

Comment: "it will call to both function of tvguidecom and skyuk at the same time". No it won't, it will call one, then immediately call the other, as it goes through your program in order.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is having your functions returning a boolean so you can check if you should continue the process.

I guess the function `tvguidecom` looks like:

```
function tvguidecom() {
    // do something without return value
}
```

Add a return value in it:

```
function tvguidecom() {
    // do something
    return $status;
}
```

So in your code you can test for the return value

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    if (tvguidecom($row)) {
        skyuk($row);
    }
}
```

*Note*: on a different topic, you shouldn't use anymore mysql extension because it is deprecated. You should use instead mysqli or pdo.

Comment: thank you very much for this, so how can i check if the data is return to true or false when using `if (tvguidecom($row))` and how i can check more than 1 function when I add more functions?

Comment: @Rob it depends of your data. You have to test it in your function and decide if the result is good or not.

Comment: when I try your code `if (tvguidecom($row)) {
        skyuk($row);
    }` it will call the skyuk function but i want to call the tvguidecom function if the data is return otherwise call the skyuk function. It should be look like this `if (tvguidecom($row)) 
       {
          tvguidecom($row);
       }
       else if (skyuk($row)) 
       {
          skyuk($row);
       }` but when i try it i still get the same result. Any idea?

Comment: @Rob I don't understand what you want to achieve. What are those function doing. I think you should update your OP to add the detail of those functions.

Comment: I have told you what I want to achieve. I'm calling the script when I click the link on my site and I want to check that if I get the return data then do something otherwise call the next function. Hope this make sense?

Comment: I understand that part. What I don't understand is what data

Comment: Great, well when I click the link it will get the link in a database and it will connect to the site to get the data. I dont want to get the data outside of that site, example: i want to get the data from google and not outside of google. Hope it make sense?

Comment: @Rob Please share your functions to understand. I am lost

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
   // this ensures that `tvguidecom()` does its stuff, and `skyuk()` 
   // waits for results returned by the function.
   skyuk(tvguidecom($row));
}

function tvguidecom($row) {
  // do stuffs, returns original input $row;
  return $row;  
}
```

---

** Another approach, [callbacks](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/).**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
   tvguidecom($row, callback);
}
```

and fn:

```
tvguidecom(a, callback) {
  // dostuffs and when complete
  callback( result );
}
```

** syntax may be incorrect, refer to link supplied. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, how i can check which function either of tvguidecom or skyuk is return to true?

Comment: in that case, if( tvguidecom( $row) ) { skyuk( $row ) }. This means, tvguidecom has to return a boolean or both if( tvguidecom( $row)  and  skyuk( $row )  ) {  //do something  }

Comment: what about if i more function and how i can check if the function has return as a boolean?

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense. Although the question mentions things happening "at the same time", they are only ever run one after the other. Adding nesting and callbacks won't actually change the order anything happens.

Comment: if, it seems you are expanding your question. there are a multiple solutions but given the defined problem, assumptions has to be made. if there are 'n' conditions, there are design patterns or algorithms to approach it. Divide and Conquer, break down the problem into solvable chunks in your scenario.

Comment: hmm, yes i gave a direct answer and an alternative approach for further knowledge to approach the problem given limited context, but I only have the intentions to help, perhaps it may be useful but it may not.